# Getting result from queryCommandValue on selected text

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

There is any solution how to return value from `queryCommandValue` for selected text?
I know about `queryCommandValue('bold')` return **string** `true` or `false` (not boolean!).
I try prepare some small WYSIWYG editor, but...

The question is how to get values from selected text, like as: *the selected text is bolded and underlined*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way. That's because `queryCommandValue` isn't telling you the state of the selected text, it's about the input. As in, if you select a paragraph that is both bold and not bold, `queryCommandValue` can't tell you that some of the text is bold and some of the text is not bold. Essentially, it tells you the value of the *next input*; in this example, if you press a character-key will that be bold or not (here, it will depend on where you started your selection: inside the bold format or not).

Also, you should know you can use `document.queryCommandState` to get a boolean returned. Of course, it only works for boolean values, things like color, font you will still want to use `queryCommandValue`

Comment: Okey, I use some like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vvCzD/1/, and for each command type we must write some code, how do this without duplicate lot of codes in line 4-6 and 8-18 in Javascript panel?

Comment: @kicaj Well, that's just a regular JS question. If you store the commands in an array, you can just loop over them in order of the buttons and set them in just 3 lines of code. Here's an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/vvCzD/10/

Comment: i forgot about loops, Your code is cool, i must rewrite my methods to array, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? It's get style values

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
console.log(selection.anchorNode.parentNode.style);
```

And this get tag name:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
console.log(selection.anchorNode.parentNode.tagName);
```